# Is it possible to declare an element in DTD file for two attributes with the same value? XML question

Tags: html, xml, dtd

Maybe you can help me with this problem. I noticed that there is an attribute called "order" in the xml with a value of 1 and 2. My question is, What  attribute and value I should put on my DTD file? I tried to add 2 !ATTLIST with both values 1 and 2, but my program (Oxygen) only allows me to put 1. I did some research about this and I couldn't find any useful information. If anybody can give me a hand with this I will appreciate it.

**XML file:**

```xml
<steps>
<step order="1">
Mix all ingredients except oil.  Shape mixture into 4 patties, each about 3 1/2 inches in diameter.  Cover and refrigerate about 1 1/2 hours or until firm.</step>
<step order="2">
Heat oil (1 inch) in deep fryer or 10-inch skillet to 375.  Fry patties in oil 4 to 5 minutes, turning once, until golden brown on both sides.  Drain on paper towels.</step>
</steps>
```

**DTD File:**

```xml
<!ELEMENT step (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST step order CDATA "1">
```

Comment: Do you want that the `order="..."` attribute can only have the values "1" or "2"?

Comment: Hello. No, i am actually doing an external DTD for this xml file. The xml file has these two attributes with different values. I only want to know how to declare those into the DTD file. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the list of possible values for an attribute, as defined in the XML specification in chapter [3.3.1 Attribute Types](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types):

> [54]      AttType    ::=      StringType | TokenizedType | EnumeratedType
>
> [57]      EnumeratedType     ::=      NotationType | Enumeration
>
> [59]      Enumeration    ::=      '(' S? Nmtoken (S? '|' S? Nmtoken)* S? ')'

In your case you can write the DTD as follow:

```
<!ELEMENT steps (step+)>
<!ELEMENT step (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST step order (1|2) #IMPLIED >
```

This way the only possible values for that attribute are "1" or "2". Depending on if the attribute is required you can choose between `#IMPLIED` and `#REQUIRED`.